# Will a transfer go through on a testnet transaction on meta mask to luno

Tags: blockchain, wallets, metamask, address.transfer

What if you sent your ETH on the Ropsten testnet via Metamask to an ETH platform gateway like Luno (https://www.luno.com) ? Will you receive your Ether and will it reflect on that account?

I've done that and I'm still waiting for it to reflect on my account...

Answer (score 1):

Testnet ETH, like that found on Ropsten in MetaMask, is different than real ETH, like that found on Luno. So no, I don't think it will show up in Luno.

You can click the drop-down in MetaMask to change between mainnet and testnet though and in theory you would be able to send ETH between Luno and MetaMask without issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Testnets, such as Ropsten or Rinkeby are for development purposes. As such, the ethers are just fake ones used to test out Dapps.